# Grid in manipulate

Tags: manipulate, grid-layouts

I am trying to plot two functions using Manipulate which use the same sliders.
When I use Grid to to this the text, "Grid[]" also appears in my output.
Using List also causes a similar problem

Is there a way around this?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: That `Grid[]` appears in the output suggests a syntax error.  To obtain  help from readers, please provide your code.

Answer (score 5):

```
Manipulate[Grid[{{
    Plot[Sin[x + a], {x, -3, 3}],
    Plot[BesselJ[x + a, 2], {x, -3, 3}]
    },{
    Plot[Cos[x + a], {x, -3, 3}],
    Plot[BesselJ[x + a, 4], {x, -3, 3}] 
   }}],
 {a, -3, 1}]
```

[image]